# Joining table in postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have a database that stores  `username` and `password`. The table is `logintable` as shown in the picture.

[image]

similarly, I have a table called `userdetails` that stores the details of a particular user as shown here:

[image]

Now, using the query `select * from ..` in `postgres`,  how do I retrieve all the details of a particular user when he signs in with his `username` and `password` ? I mean for different user different records needs to be retrieved.

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're trying to get? It would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Somwhat like in social media.. for a particular user, his perticular details..

Comment: How do you know which login belongs to which user?

Comment: And never store passwords in plain text. Use a salted hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to join logintable to userdetails. There should be a table that contains both username and firstname/lastname or other way to identify the user in userdetails. If you are making this schema yourself, consider just putting the username in userdetails.